# MongoDB is not reporting to close connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running through the [getting started tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/insert/) to evaluate MongoDB for use in production.

Tailing the server logs it showed the following: in the last 5 lines `mongod` reports it is closing connections but the count for the number of connections open is not decreasing.  Is this expected behaviour?

```
$ tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=86710 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=As-MacBook-Air.local
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin As-MacBook-Air.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-11-29T15:10:13.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2015-11-29T15:10:13.435+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-11-29T15:14:21.158+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52667 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.169+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:52667 (0 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.175+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52668 #2 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.176+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52669 #3 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.176+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52670 #4 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.176+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52671 #5 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.179+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52672 #6 (5 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.183+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:52668 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.184+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:52669 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.184+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:52670 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.184+0000 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:52671 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-29T15:14:21.184+0000 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:52672 (0 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.136+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52799 #7 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.137+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:52799 (0 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.142+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52800 #8 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.142+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52801 #9 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.144+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52802 #10 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.144+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52803 #11 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.145+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52804 #12 (5 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.153+0000 I INDEX    [conn9] allocating new ns file /usr/local/var/mongodb/test.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-29T15:25:39.209+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /usr/local/var/mongodb/test.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-29T15:25:39.209+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory /usr/local/var/mongodb/_tmp
2015-11-29T15:25:39.328+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /usr/local/var/mongodb/test.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.118 secs
2015-11-29T15:25:39.374+0000 I WRITE    [conn9] insert test.restaurants query: { address: { street: "2 Avenue", zipcode: "10075", building: "1480", coord: [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ] }, borough: "Manhattan", cuisine: "Italian", grades: [ { date: new Date(1412121600000), grade: "A", score: 11 }, { date: new Date(1389830400000), grade: "B", score: 17 } ], name: "Vella", restaurant_id: "41704620", _id: ObjectId('565b18f333b46874536e90de') } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 8 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 179 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 4 } } } 221ms
2015-11-29T15:25:39.374+0000 I COMMAND  [conn9] command test.$cmd command: insert { insert: "restaurants", documents: [ { address: { street: "2 Avenue", zipcode: "10075", building: "1480", coord: [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ] }, borough: "Manhattan", cuisine: "Italian", grades: [ { date: new Date(1412121600000), grade: "A", score: 11 }, { date: new Date(1389830400000), grade: "B", score: 17 } ], name: "Vella", restaurant_id: "41704620", _id: ObjectId('565b18f333b46874536e90de') } ], ordered: true } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 8 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 179 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 4 } } } 221ms
2015-11-29T15:25:39.384+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:52800 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.384+0000 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:52801 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.384+0000 I NETWORK  [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:52802 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.385+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11] end connection 127.0.0.1:52803 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-29T15:25:39.385+0000 I NETWORK  [conn12] end connection 127.0.0.1:52804 (2 connections now open)
```

I started the MongoDB server with:

```
$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Other details:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F1096
$ mongod -version
db version v3.0.7
git version: nogitversion
$ cat /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, MongoDB is holding a queue of connections that it dispenses on request, not each request translates to opening a connection and closing it when response is delivered.

I've experienced a large number of connections when working from multiple services with the same MongoDB and we had to limit within our app the number of created connections and reuse same connections rather than create a new one for each request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In part that's definitely very useful.  Thank you.  Due to the (simple) nature of the tutorial I was already reusing the connection.  My main concern is that MongoDB is mis-counting open connections when it itself is reporting `end connection`... I'm worried about using it in production if it's going to "leak" connections and presumably the associate resources with them.